# Spring Integration Read All Files as a Single Message

Tags: spring-integration

How do we read all the files from a directory as a single `Message<List<File>>`? The usecase is to send a status report by iterating all the files and reading their filenames as a single message.

Please share some guidance if a custom `MessageSource` has to be implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `MessageSource` could be a simple as this:

```
IntegrationFlow.fromSupplier(() -> new File("myDir").list())
```

Then you need to play with an appropriate trigger for the poller when you would like to list those file names.

You also can do this as a part of a `handle()` as a reaction to some incoming event, e.g. you ask for those names from some user call.